# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado

Tags: php, pdo

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Estou tendo muita dor de cabeça para conectar meu código em um arquivo `.dbf`, e não encontrei nenhuma solução após rodar a internet por dois dias seguidos...

Esse é o código em `PHP`

```
<?php

$connection = 'odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};DefaultDir=C:\;Exclusive=NO';

$pdo = new PDO($connection);
```

Configurei já a fonte de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Habilitei os drivers `extension=pdo_odbc` e `extension=odbc` no `php.ini`

Feito isso tudo, ao executar o algoritmo ele retorna um:

> Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trevas\action\lerdbf.php on line 5

Mas, ao abrir o log de erros do `Apache`, ele mostra isso:

> [Wed Jul 17 17:52:33.530567 2019] [php7:error] [pid 1660:tid 1960] [client ::1:51411] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados n\xe3o encontrado e nenhum driver padr\xe3o especificado in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trevas\action\lerdbf.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Trevas\action\lerdbf.php(5): PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={Mi...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trevas\action\lerdbf.php on line 5

Não sei se a solução é fácil ou difícil, mas esse código funciona em outras máquinas com o mesmo Sistema Operacional (**Windows 10**), mesma versão do `Apache` e do `PHP`... Já não sei mais o que tentar.

Comment: Na documentação [PDO_ODBC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) está informando que a biblioteca `php_pdo_odbc.dll` deve ser habilitada no `php.ini`, como você fez, **assim permitindo que o PHP se conecte com qualquer Banco de Dado catalogado como DNS DE SISTEMA**. Na foto da para perceber que seu Banco de Dados  está catalogado como DNS de usuário.

Comment: Augusto, fiz o mesmo procedimento para catalogar como DSN de Sistema, e mesmo assim não funciona...

Comment: Eu que você fez `extension=pdo_odbc` e `extension=odbc`, mas o  `extension=php_pdo.dll` o adicionou no php ini? E verificou a existência php_pdo.dll?

Comment: Augusto, pesquisei sobre essa extensão pois não a tenho aqui, e vi que deveria ter vindo por padrão com o PHP... Não consigo encontrar uma fonte confiável para baixar essa dll para a versão 7.3.7 do PHP... Conhece alguma fonte?

Comment: Eu não recomendo a ninguém esse tipo de procedimento por questões de segurança. Eu recomendo ou reinstalar a versão ou então fazer o upgrade.

Comment: Augusto, obrigado pelas respostas, mas tive que encontrar outra solução...
Segui a nota de contribuição que está no manual do dbase do PHP, e foi muito mais fácil rs 
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dbase.php